# Reference request. Rigorous numerical optimization

Tags: reference-request, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am looking for texts on Numerical optimization that are closer to Analysis definition-theorem-proof style texts.

EDIT: This is my first acquaintance with numerical optimization. My institution requires that I choose my master's thesis topic in a subfield of numerical optimization. But I'm really fond of Analysis and doing proofs so I want to find resources that are of the same style as "the lecture notes series on nonlinear optimization by A. Nemirovski" and "lectures on modern convex optimization" by A. Nemirovski and Aharon Ben-Tal so that I keep learning/doing proofs all the time.

**My background**

- In analysis

Almost covered baby Rudin and the theory of Banach and Hilbert spaces (level: kreyszig - Shilov), measure and integration theory (Kolmogorov)].

- In linear algebra

I followed terry tao's lecture notes and currently reading finite dimensional space by P. Halmos.

Comment: What particular aspects of optimization are you interested in?  Convex analysis, convex optimization, smooth non-convex optimization, optimal control and variational calculus,  discrete optimization, convergence theorems, rates of convergence?  computational complexity results?  Are you interested in problems on $R^{n}$ or in more general settings (Hilbert spaces or Banach spaces)?  What's your background in analysis?  linear algebra and matrix theory?  computer science?

Comment: What texts have you looked at that don't satisfy your desire for a definition-theorem-proof presentation?  In other words, what are you comparing against?

Comment: I added this information to the question. Thank you.

Comment: The two books that you mentioned will give you a solid basis in the mathematics behind first-order methods for convex optimization.  There are lots of different directions in which you could go from there.  So, what do you want to learn next?

Comment: I have not fully read them yet but I read some sections so I think I will decide after reading them. But I don't know what is research like in numerical optimization. But my intuition is telling me that people try to invent optimization algorithms and prove their convergence whether we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a Hilbert or a Banach space

Comment: I would begin with the excellent book by Prof. Amir Beck https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611973655?mobileUi=0